# How to understand the lectures on the fly as much as possible?

Tags: learning

My problem is, that during the lectures my mind just goes blank and I cannot follow for a few seconds. Consequently I will have trouble catching up with what was just explained. This repeats more and more as the time goes on.

So the information I am hearing just turns into white-noise as the lecture proceeds. Obviously this is something that other people also have to struggle with. But I feel (there is no other way to tell) that this issue is more hindering to me than to others.

Maybe you others have your ways to cope with that. I am curious.

All the best

Comment: Read what will be covered in your books before the lecture so you are somewhat familiar with the material.

Comment: Get the syllabus & read one of the recommended text books before the lectures even start. The lectures themselves will then be a breeze ... simply reinforcing what you already know ...

Comment: I'd say change your major before things get nasty.

Comment: don't change your major, you will have the same problem even if you do ... just kidding :) Apart from the very sound advice to read the book in advance, I would add get enough sleep the night before

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adult_attention_deficit_hyperactivity_disorder

Comment: Stop writing, I don't know why some people tell students to "write". Probably a terrible habit picked up from high school, but your brain is never fully active if you try to do 3 different activities at the same time (read the board, write in your notebook, and listen)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that helps me is taking pictures of the board periodically throughout the lecture. This allows me to spend less time frantically copying notes as to not miss anything, and spend more time actually listening and processing the information. Also, I would assume that your professor doesn't mind questions during lecture. If something catches you off guard and pulls you out of it (your brain might just be stopping to see if things are making sense), I would just raise your hand and ask the professor to re-explain it. Most of the time, there are other students in the class who are hung up on the same exact point.

Answer (score -1):

Understanding on the fly is possible when you already know intimately what is being lectured. This intimate knowledge comes after you have spent time and effort in something called study: a process whereby a pre-concept (a new notion of which one can have some hypotheses about their meaning thanks to intuition coming from prior knowledge) tranforms into a concept through an activity of check of its coungrence with respect to all concepts already owned by the learner. So my suggestion is not to attend lectures unless they are given by authorities, and in this case do it after having studied.

Comment: This is "educationese" word salad.  "...pre-concept transforms into a concept through an activity of check of its coungrence (sic and ??!?)..."  GAAAA!